# Loading local html file into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a local html file into div, but it does seem to work (alert is displayed, but no content is displayed to the page).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>                   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="blog"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript (test.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#blog").load("tester.html", function() {
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
});
```

Loaded HTML file (tester.html):

```
<p>
   The word <strong>hello</strong> should be bold.
</p>
```

Comment: Is you #blog div visible? It have width and height?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOP** *(Same Origin Policy)*.
 This will not work in **Chrome**.
Try in **Firefox** or on **Localhost** or on an online **server**.

`AJAX` cannot work from `file://` but `http://`

Comment: Thanks it worked in FF. I've been pretty frustrated with this for a while.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. It's just kind of a stupid implementation.

Comment: @Andy I believe you, I had headaches at my time too. You're welcome

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, What means 'SOP'? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @John well... Same Origin Policy

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why are you doing this, but i seriously not recommend it. Browsers forbid this behaviour for security reasons, you can't load things from the file system.

If you are testing, use somthing like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is really easy to set up. It will also give a more real view of how web sites work.
If you where actually trying to use this as a real web page, I recommend you search another way to do it.

Comment: 1. Not true. 2. What so wrong in creating AJAX driven websites?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan — 1. Yes it is. 2. Plenty, but that isn't what this answer says isn't recommended (which is trying to do Ajax over `file://` instead of `http://`).

Comment: Ajax web sites rock, i use angularjs myself for creating webapps. I don't recommend loading local files, is not a browser function nor is a real use case

Comment: @donnanicolas I'm sure he's using local files because he's testing locally. He just needs to setup a local web server, like you suggested.

Comment: I am just testing locally. When decide I upload the site, the loaded html files will be hosted.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if you just want to make a test for a image, I do suggest that you can use an relative path to refer to the image. For example:

```
cp ~/1.png ~/Workspace/html/app/1.png
vim ~/Workspace/html/app/test.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="border-radius: 5px; border: 0px;">
        <img src="test.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```